# Custom button style alignment wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I tried modifying a button style in order to remove the Chrome System-like button. Everything works out fine there but the content of the button will not align properly at the center of the button.

Button Style:

```
<Style x:Key="NoChrome" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Button declaration:

```
<Button Content="Button" Canvas.Left="141" Canvas.Top="324" Width="75" Style="{DynamicResource NoChrome}"/>
```

Comment: HorizontalAlignment="Center" ?

Comment: It'd be horizontalContentAlignment but i already have that set to Center

Comment: Set on ContentPresenter?

Comment: That was the thing. Thank you for you have saved my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"

You typically use the ContentPresenter in the ControlTemplate of a ContentControl to specify where the content is to be added. Every ContentControl type has a ContentPresenter in its default ControlTemplate.

When a ContentPresenter object is in a ControlTemplate of a ContentControl, the Content, ContentTemplate, and ContentTemplateSelector properties get their values from the properties of the same names of the ContentControl. You can have the ContentPresenter property get the values of these properties from other properties of the templated parent by setting the ContentSource property or binding to them.

```
<Style x:Key="NoChrome" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

See [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx)